# Cast Multiple Double Variables in R to Integer

Tags: r

If I have multiple doubles all stored as variables:

```
float_1 = 5.0
float_2 = 3.1
...
float_5 = 3.1
```

How can I update all variables to become numeric without repeatedly writing as.integer().  What I was thinking was something like this:

```
vapply(c(float_1,float_2,float_3,float_4,float_5, as.integer()))
```

But this doesn't work as R tells me `as.integer()' is not a function, character or symbol.`  In addition, even if this did work, this would just return a vector of 5 doubles, rather than updating each variable.

Edit: To clarify, I obviously don't care if 3.1 becomes 3. But I need each variable's type to become numeric as I funnel these variables into a reticulate function that requires integers.

Comment: `as.integer`, no parens.

Comment: but that will return a vector with the converted numbers, not change them in-place. You could use something like `for (nm in ls(pattern="^float_")) assign(nm, as.integer(get(nm)))`, but that is horribly inefficient, anti-R-idiomatic, and suggests that the original decision to define all of these variables independently and then convert them could be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments come with quite fitting answers. It is however often recommended to store variables like these in a vector or a list, which would trivialize these kind of operations. Building on the comments from @r2evans, one method would be

```
#Unlist to store as vector, remove to store as list
vars <- unlist(mget(var_name <- ls(pattern = '^float_([0-9]*)')))
vars <- as.integer(vars) #lapply(vars, as.integer) #<= list  version
#names get lost in "translation", so we'll have to add the names again
names(vars) <- var_name 
#rename if wanted
names(vars) <- gsub('^float', 'integer', names(vars))
vars
#output
# integer_1 integer_11  integer_2  integer_3 
#         5         11          3          4
```

after which we can extract the specific variable of interest as `vars['integer_1']`.

## data

```
float_1 = 5.0
float_2 = 3.1
float_3 <- 4.2
float_11 <- 11.2
```